# How to represent Geodjango model in a django-leaflet leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, django, leaflet, geodjango, django-leaflet

In my django app I am using Geodjango, django-leaflet and leaflet-ajax. I have a route model with a LineStringField. I want to render that route in a template using a leaflet map. I have tried the following code with other models (those that have a Point field instead). But for any reason this  code is not working with the RouteModel. The leaflet map shows nothing. How can I add that route to the "gis" leaflet map

Here is the model definition

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
    class RouteModel(models.Model):
        
        name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Nombre"), max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    
        route_type_id = models.ForeignKey("RouteTypeModel", verbose_name=_("Tipo"),
                                                     blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                                     related_name="routes")
    
        start_date = models.DateField(verbose_name=_("Fecha inicio"))
        end_date = models.DateField(verbose_name=_("Fecha fin"))
    
        route_geom = models.LineStringField(verbose_name=_("Ruta"), srid=4326)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'riesgo_route'
            managed = True
            verbose_name = _('Ruta')
            verbose_name_plural = _('Rutas')
```

Here is the ajax view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def route_get_location(request,pk):
    route=serialize('geojson',RouteModel.objects.filter(id=pk))
    return HttpResponse(route,content_type='json')

urlpatterns = [
 # url definitions
 path('ruta/localizar/<str:pk>', route_get_location, name='route_locate'),
]
```

And in the template:

```
 {% leaflet_map "gis" callback="window.our_layers" %}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function our_layers(map,options){
        //var datasets= new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'mailapp:polygon_get_location' %}" ,{});
        var datasets= new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'riesgo:route_locate' route.id %}" ,{});
        
        datasets.addTo(map);                    
       
    }
                                
                                    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the Issue: I had a duplicate of the route_get_location function in another file. So the this post is a working example of how to represent a  Geodjango model using django-leaflet and leaflet-ajax